# Calling function in main file from component

Tags: react-native, react-functional-component

I have recently refactored my app from using Class components to Functional components and having issues with a few last things.

My `Home.js` looks like the following (simplified):

```
// imports....
import { StartStopButtons } from "../components/Button";

export default ({ navigation }) => {

  const [scrollEnabled, setScrollEnabled] = useState(false);
  const [elapsedMilliseconds, setElapsedMilliseconds] = useState(0);
  const [isRunning, setIsRunning] = useState(false);
  const [startTime, setStartTime] = useState(false);
  const [stopTime, setStopTime] = useState(false);
  const [isReset, setIsReset] = useState(true);

  start = () => {
    console.log("START");
    // stuff
  };

  reset = () => {
    console.log("RESET");
    // stuff
  };

  stop = () => {
    console.log("STOP");
    // stuff
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <StartStopButtons
          isRunning={isRunning}
          isReset={isReset}
          elapsedMilliseconds={elapsedMilliseconds}
        />
    </View>
  );
};
```

My `StartStopButtons` has a different look, depending of the current state, it will either display `Start`, `Stop` or `Reset` and call the corresponding function. I am currently putting this intelligence in another file, my `Button.js` file.

`Button.js` :

```
//imports....

export const StartStopButtons = ({
  isRunning,
  isReset,
  elapsedMilliseconds,
}) => {
  if (isRunning && isReset === false) {
    return (
      <View>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={stop}>
          <Text>Stop</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>

        <TouchableOpacity onPress={pause}>
          <Text>Pause</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  } else {
    if (elapsedMilliseconds === 0) {
      return (
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={start}>
          <Text>Start</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={reset}>
          <Text>Reset</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      );
    }
  }
};
```

Before the refactoring, I was using `this.state.start`, `this.state.stop` to call my `start` and `stop` functions, located in `Home.js`.

How can I achieve that now? Is there a better approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the functions as props exactly like how you pass `isRunning`, `isReset`, and `elapsedMilliseconds`.

But please add `const` before function names as well.

```js
// imports....
import { StartStopButtons } from "../components/Button";

export default ({ navigation }) => {

  const [scrollEnabled, setScrollEnabled] = useState(false);
  const [elapsedMilliseconds, setElapsedMilliseconds] = useState(0);
  const [isRunning, setIsRunning] = useState(false);
  const [startTime, setStartTime] = useState(false);
  const [stopTime, setStopTime] = useState(false);
  const [isReset, setIsReset] = useState(true);

  const start = () => {
    console.log("START");
    // stuff
  };

  const reset = () => {
    console.log("RESET");
    // stuff
  };

  const stop = () => {
    console.log("STOP");
    // stuff
  };

  const pause = () => {};

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <StartStopButtons
          start={start}
          stop={stop}
          reset={reset}
          pause={pause}
          isRunning={isRunning}
          isReset={isReset}
          elapsedMilliseconds={elapsedMilliseconds}
        />
    </View>
  );
};
```

and use them like

```js
//imports....

export const StartStopButtons = ({
  start,
  stop,
  reset,
  pause,
  isRunning,
  isReset,
  elapsedMilliseconds,
}) => {
  if (isRunning && isReset === false) {
    return (
      <View>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={stop}>
          <Text>Stop</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>

        <TouchableOpacity onPress={pause}>
          <Text>Pause</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  } else {
    if (elapsedMilliseconds === 0) {
      return (
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={start}>
          <Text>Start</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={reset}>
          <Text>Reset</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      );
    }
  }
};
```